# How can I add an Inspector field to a Godot 4 extension written in Rust?

Tags: rust, godot

I am writing an extension for Godot 4 written in Rust using the godot wrapper crate around the gdext bindings.

The tutorial (https://godot-rust.github.io/book/gdext/intro/hello-world.html#custom-rust-apis) shows that you can annotate functions that should be callable from gdscript using the `#[func]` directive.

I would like to add a parameter that appears in the Inspector so that users of the Godot GUI can alter some of the properties of a Node-derived instance from my extension.

How do I add this capability to my extension?  Do I annotate a public field of the struct?  Do I annotate a setter/getter pair?

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no experience with Godot + Rust. This appears to be the relevant documentation: https://godot-rust.github.io/book/gdnative/bind/properties.html which uses `#[property]` on a public field - What you linked suggest `#[export]` might be valid or necessary, I'm not sure if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

As Theraot noticed (because he is not blind) the proper annotation to mark a field of a rust struct to make it appear in the inspector is `#[export]`.

```
#[derive(GodotClass)]
#[class(base=Node)]
struct RemoteRenderer {
    #[base]
    base: Base<Node>,

    encoder: Option<Encoder>,
    png_sink: PNGSink,

    display: GLDisplay,
    context: GLContext,

    #[export]
    enable: bool,
}
```

From https://godot-rust.github.io/book/gdext/intro/hello-world.html#custom-rust-apis :
" API attributes typically follow the GDScript keyword names: class, func, signal, export, var, ... "

Comment: thanks for not making me RTFM. nice to see gdext is becoming used enough to get answers on stackoverflow showing up on google now :)